# Python command in anaconda prompt not working

Tags: python, windows, conda

I have downloaded the Anaconda python 3.7 version on my Windows.
When I am writing the "python" command on anaconda prompt its opening new window of Microsoft soft to install python 3.8.

Comment: Did you create and activate an environment?

Comment: @AMC Doesn't the base environment activated by default in an Anaconda prompt?

Comment: @oszkar I believe so, although I don’t use the Anaconda Prompt, and I deactivated that functionality from the “normal” command line. In any case you **really** should be using a separate environment.

Answer (score 0):

If "python" doesn't work, it's usually "py" or "python3".

Comment: even for "py" and "python3" its opening Microsoft store which is asking me to download python3.8

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in your environment. Open anaconda prompt and type `conda activate [name of your environment]` and then try to run `python`, `pip`, `python3` or `pip3`

Answer (score 0):

anaconda python 3.7 is a package management and deployment software. The idea behind it, is that it allows you to create environments where you have access to such packages and is, therefore, able to develop things using python language or any other language.

I believe that you are willing to develop stuff in python: in the anaconda prompt, you should create an environment, as described https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands

`$ condo create -n envpy38 python=3.8`

after activating the newly created environment, `$ condo activate envpy38` , you can specify that you want the python 3.8 package, by using 
`$ condo install -c anaconda python=3.8`

Then, you will be able to use the python tool to do whatever you are willing to using python 3.8...